# How to dynamically add or remove a Text Input in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I add a text input in React Native with the click of a button? For example, I would press the "+" button and it would add a text input at the bottom of the View.

here is the code i found in another page but when i click on the plus nothing happen

```
var textInput = []

let addTextInput = (key) => {
    textInput.push(<TextInput key={key} style={{color:'red',borderColor:'red'}}/>);
    { textInput }
}

let orgServiceandWorkHours = (
    <View>
        <Button title='+' onPress={() => 
       addTextInput(textInput.length)} />
    {textInput.map((value, index) => {
      return value
    })}
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Post some code and show others what you have tried so far

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407581/how-to-dynamically-add-a-text-input-in-react-native/45407976)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a full example (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/mature-carrot) and the code below.

```js
export default function App() {

  const [numTextInputs,setNumTextInputs] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <View style={styles.parent}>
        {/* Button */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setNumTextInputs(val=>val+1)} style={styles.buttton}>
              <Text style={styles.text}> Add TextInput </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <ScrollView style={{flex:1}} >
              {[...Array(numTextInputs).keys()].map(key=>{
                return <TextInput key={key} placeholder="Here Man" style={{width:200,height:100,borderColor:"blue",margin:10,borderWidth:1}}/>
              })}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent:{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"},
  textInput:{width:"80%",height:"5%",backgroundColor:"lightgray",margin:20,borderRadius:10,textAlign:"center"},
  buttton:{width:"80%",height:"12%",backgroundColor:"lightblue",borderRadius:10,
        justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"
        },
  text:{fontSize:30,fontFamily:"bold",color:"black"},
})
```

Comment: thats not what i mean , i asked if i can build a button that every time i press on it it will add a new TextInput on the page

Comment: Okay there it is click the expo link

Comment: great , thank you!